# Using a randomfile in folder?

Tags: bash, file, random

Right now my Script looks like that:

```
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i videos/fitness"$(( RANDOM % 8 ))".mp4
```

It searches for all videos in my folder that starts with "fitness".

```
fitness1.mp4

fitness2.mp4

fitness3.mp4
```

and so on...

and it takes 1 randomly between `1-8 ( im using /fitness"$(( RANDOM % 8 ))".mp4 )`

Is there a way to just use a random mp4 file from the folder, no matter whats the name is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Shuf

Use the `shuf` command:

```
shuf -en1 dir/*.mp4
```

If you don't have `shuf` (for instance on BSD), you can write your own `shuf -en1` very easily:

```
shufen1() {
    shift "$((RANDOM % $#))" # slightly biased towards small numbers, at most 32767
    printf %s\\n "$1"
}
```

#### Pure bash solution using arrays

For completeness, here is a pure bash solution. However, this has the same problems as the self-written `shufen1` function.

```
a=(dir/*.mp4)
printf %s\\n "${a[RANDOM % ${#a[@]}]}"
```

#### Using these solutions

Both commands work under the assumption that there is at least one mp4-file written in lowercase letters. You can use case insensitive matching using `shopt -s nocaseglob`.

You might want to set `shopt -s failglob`  to get an error in case there is no such file, otherwise the literal string `dir/*.mp4` will be printed.

To use any of these solutions, write them into a subshell:

```
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i "$(shuf -en1 videos/*.mp4)"
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i "$(a=(videos/*.mp4); printf %s\\n "${a[RANDOM % ${#a[@]}]}")"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find videos -type f -name '*.mp4' | shuf -n1
```

Find files with the name `*.mp4`, randomly permute the list of names and output a single filename.

```
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i "$(find videos -type f -name '*.mp4' | shuf -n1)"
```